# When I try running my flutter code on an iOS simulator for an app I'm developing, I get ERROR RUNNING POD INSTALL

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A cloud_firestore
  A cloud_firestore_web
  A firebase_auth
  A firebase_auth_web
  A firebase_core
  A firebase_core_web
  - Flutter
  - flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
  - image_picker
  - path_provider_linux
  - shared_preferences
  - shared_preferences_linux
  - shared_preferences_macos
  - shared_preferences_web

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_linux` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_linux/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_linux` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_linux/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_macos/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_web/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.1/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.1/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.29.0/Firebase.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.29.0/Firebase.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.1/Firebase.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"2150-kZGGyOEZ3ZNypF/R3ReoqUK8GJI"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.0/Firebase.podspec.json, 
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.15.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.16.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.18.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.19.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.21.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.22.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.23.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.24.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.25.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.27.1/Firebase.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.0/Firebase.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.28.1/Firebase.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.29.0/Firebase.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.29.0/Firebase.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.3.1/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/e/3/GTMSessionFetcher/1.4.0/GTMSessionFetcher.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.9.2/FirebaseCore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.5.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.5.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.5.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"901-dTX+aVc3+MWzUFhCkqcLf4/wNXs"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.5.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.9.2/FirebaseCore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.9.1/FirebaseCore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.9.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.8.1/FirebaseCore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/6.8.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_b_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.9/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.5.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.4.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/3/c/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/1.3.0/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_6_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.0.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.0.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.1.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.1.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.1.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"106a-rwx5GT3Fms03YwtIM9DcaRKua9U"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.0.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"106a-ikDLGUrSQrb23+csFP5A/GfE3Nc"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.1.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/1.30905.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/1.30905.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/1.30905.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/1.30905.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.1.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/6/a/GoogleDataTransport/7.0.0/GoogleDataTransport.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.9/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.8/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.7/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.6/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.5/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.4/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.3/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.2/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2.1/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/b/5/PromisesObjC/1.2/PromisesObjC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_9_f.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.1/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.1/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.2/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.2/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.3/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.3/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.2/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"dd9-Q2wt6V9CSV+7ba+Gvr3kg+ZnBsM"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.1/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"dd9-OQFrw41KGdZ3KNMOdbXcz4IXbaE"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.3/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"dd9-Xqewh4Nj+exmvc7gwprYddG1Eaw"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.3/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/9/f/FirebaseFirestore/1.16.3/FirebaseFirestore.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_3_8_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/1.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_8_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0-pre2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0-pre2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0-pre2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"fd1f-XWlJScwOdamUKH0UhTZuas6Cais"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"fcf7-BvZHIR88Tj46rgfjDhIKBKffXTY"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.31.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_a_d_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/a/leveldb-library/1.22/leveldb-library.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! 
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.0/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/8/7/gRPC-C++/1.28.2/gRPC-C++.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_1_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0-pre1/gRPC-Core.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0-pre1/gRPC-Core.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0-pre2/gRPC-Core.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0-pre2/gRPC-Core.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0-pre1/gRPC-Core.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"16ec0-6kkG9YLCNiWfQLyJiP66/fXwP2Y"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"16e93-2fNqXv/8IplaxmG0HdOwgPmCow8"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0-pre2/gRPC-Core.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"16ec0-JxWIpiZlVT6sAplINlIpS2iZ2vw"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.31.0/gRPC-Core.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.28.2/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.28.2/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/1/0/gRPC-Core/1.28.2/gRPC-Core.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_8_8.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.11/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.11/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.11/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"b686-N8fkG8VyWkyVQIg+4FE4VxC1XAE"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.11/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/3/8/6/abseil/0.20200225.0/abseil.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.7/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.7/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/8/8/BoringSSL-GRPC/0.0.7/BoringSSL-GRPC.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_2_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.6.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.6.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"48d-qlItzp/ZMAK6FVRGfSPOcJIyMAA"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.6.2/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"47e-X6MI4bE/g40PbcdHGawqcujFr8Q"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.7.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_2_f_7.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.5.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.5.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.5.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"9da-PFIMlRMFy/nKVOuJH/nm0f04SIE"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.5.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_3_b.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.6.2/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.6.2/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Redirecting from https://cdn.cocoapods.org/Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.7.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.7.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.6.2/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"441-jNHyidYOYpzxarAzY7nonHdrllE"
  CDN: trunk Relative path downloaded: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.7.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json, save ETag: W/"450-NF02X9EF5mgr9QhHg6U1Kj2yaCA"
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.7.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local

  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/6.7.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.5.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/2/f/7/FirebaseInstallations/1.4.0/FirebaseInstallations.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.7.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json modified during this run! Returning local

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A BoringSSL-GRPC
  A Firebase
  A FirebaseAnalytics
  A FirebaseAuth
  A FirebaseCore
  A FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
  A FirebaseFirestore
  A FirebaseInstallations
  A Flutter
  A GTMSessionFetcher
  A GoogleAppMeasurement
  A GoogleDataTransport
  A GoogleUtilities
  A PromisesObjC
  A abseil
  A cloud_firestore
  A cloud_firestore_web
  A firebase_auth
  A firebase_auth_web
  A firebase_core
  A firebase_core_web
  A flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle
  A gRPC-C++
  A gRPC-Core
  A image_picker
  A leveldb-library
  A nanopb
  A path_provider_linux
  A shared_preferences
  A shared_preferences_linux
  A shared_preferences_macos
  A shared_preferences_web

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/6w/lk6m254d5f53y8mqffcng4mh0000gp/T/d20200806-3630-9i3xm9 --template=

[!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/6w/lk6m254d5f53y8mqffcng4mh0000gp/T/d20200806-3630-9i3xm9 --template=

Cloning into '/var/folders/6w/lk6m254d5f53y8mqffcng4mh0000gp/T/d20200806-3630-9i3xm9'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Cloning into '/var/folders/6w/lk6m254d5f53y8mqffcng4mh0000gp/T/d20200806-3630-9i3xm9'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You may need to clarify what specifically you are asking in order to get the best answer.   To start, do you have CocoaPods installed on your machine, and if so, have you ran "pod install" for your project?

Comment: I got a solution to my problem.
Thank you for your concern!

Comment: Hello @Amith_ i am also getting similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333575/the-pods-runner-target-has-frameworks-with-conflicting-names-appinvokesdk-fra, can you guide me what solve your issue?

Comment: Hey @YashJain, sorry for the late reply. Coming to the issue try deleting Podfile.lock file and run flutter clean. Then go to iOS folder and run pod install. Do not forget to mention the correct version of the iOS emulator before running pod install. As my issue was that I had the latest version of iOS emulator running but I was trying to run the code which was trying to access an older version.Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Delete Podfile.lock. file and  flutter clean then go to ios folder run command

pod install